# speed of how fast my grass is growing

Tags: grass

I would hope this is not off topic. But my question is very simple. When I cut grass around my yard I have some grass that is growing faster than the rest. But the only grass that is growing faster than the rest is the stuff that I did with the weed wacker. the rest done with the mower is not growing as fast. My best guess is that one does a better cut on the grass than the other. But if anybody could explain this that would be great.

Update: I use a mix of a riding lawn mower a a push mower. Both set to about 3" in height. The blades are slightly dull on the rider and the push mower itself is new. I usually never water my grass, I let the rain do that for me. I do not use any fertilizer. I am not sure about what types of grass I have. Some areas have grass that grows thing but thick, and others that grow pretty big but few blades per plant.

I use the weed wacker around fence, the mail box, under my big trailers, around the house etc. I use .065" 5-point star twisted line but will be going to .08" twisted square once the other stuff is gone. The weed wacker is not the most powerful but is loved by the owner :). It could use a cord, or battery.

Comment: Grasses for lawns are a mix of different types of grasses.  What I am hearing is that you might have problems with your maintenance, mowing height, how you water and what you use for fertilizer...how often.  Need lots more information.  How high do you mow your grass?  How often and how much you water.  What grass species are listed for the seed you purchased?  Fertilizer...when was the last time and what was the formulation used?  Weed wacker is the worst thing one could use for a 'lawn'...sort of like using dull dull mower blades.  Send pictures and more information, answers.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you use a weed wacker on some of it and don't just cut the whole lot with the mower, is there a reason for that? And photos would be helpful.

Comment: I will do what I can for pictures. But in some areas I can not use my mower. There is fence and basic things of the such. Along my house, under the trailers and things like that. so I use the weed wacker for those areas. its .08" trimmer line

Comment: Little side question @Stormy. I have a single string trimmer. Does a dual string trimmer do cleaner cutting or doesn't make a difference. Or is simply the shape and size of the line that makes the big difference?  Thanks.

Comment: Forget the dual string trimmer.  It beats up the grass even more.  Very inaccurate from what I've experienced.  Get a fixed head to replace your bump and go, I liked the star cross section best, get rid of the shield, be very aware of your surroundings and where that line is flinging stuff (you would be amazed how far and how fast and how lethal debris can become.  The shield gives a false impression of safety and accuracy is zilch.  WEAR SAFETY GLASSES.  Gotta repeat this reminder...what matters is the proper length of both cutting lines.  Too long is completely inaccurate and can damage your

Comment: ...line trimmer's motor.  Pull both lines up, centered on the head to cut, then turn upside down and lightly touch both spinning lines to concrete or a boulder.  You will hear the sound go up as the lines are perfectly trimmed by the hard surface.  I do this each time I change out the line.  NOW you have accuracy and 'better' cutting.  Great for the occasional 'mohawk', the grass along the edges (keep your grass at 3"!!) and the edge between the concrete and the beds.  But do not do your entire lawn with a trimmer!  Keep your mower blades SHARP!  Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Yup this makes sense for me. Thank you Stormy for the good information!